# Implement maxIdle timout session using Redis

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis, spring-session

Like Spring Session with Redis persistence, how to achieve max idle timeout using Redis as cache? I need to have both global timeout and max inactive timeout. The global timeout can be achieved using `EXPIRE` command in Redis, but for max inactive time how Spring Session with Redis is implemented and is there any optimal solution using Redis to implement max inactive time?

Answer (score 1):

Implement Your cache as this, in this you've to track when this key was used.

```
public class SmartCache {
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> template;
    private String lastUsedTracker = "__inactive-duration::";

    public SmartCache(RedisTemplate<String, Object> template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    private String lastUsedKey(String key) {
        return lastUsedTracker + key;
    }

    public void put(String key, Object val, long maxRetentionTime, long maxInactiveDuration) {
        template.opsForValue().set(key, val, maxRetentionTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        template.opsForValue().set(lastUsedKey(key), maxInactiveDuration, maxInactiveDuration, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public Object get(String key) {
        // ttl has expired
        Object val = template.opsForValue().get(key);
        if (val == null) {
            return null;
        }

        // if key was inactive then nothing to be done
        Object inactiveDuration = template.opsForValue().get(lastUsedKey(key));
        if (inactiveDuration == null) {
            return null;
        }
        
        // reset ttl of inactive key as its used
        Long ttl = (Long) inactiveDuration;
        template.opsForValue().set(lastUsedKey(key), ttl, ttl, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return val;
    }

}
```